# Have two emacs. Want to use spacemacs with one and leave the other intact

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I have emacs24 and emacs25 on my machine. I want to use spacemacs with emacs24 and keep emacs25...well...as emacs. When I install spacemacs my ~/.emacs and ~/.emacs.d are changed. Both emacs start using spacemacs, which I do not want. Is there a way to have a spacemacs and an emacs at the same time. Tried looking for a solution and came across a solution to keep separate config files. But how to make emacs look for a specific config file. By the way if you still haven't guessed...I'm a noob.

Comment: emacs -l /path/to/config ?

Comment: I feel this is a duplicate of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/4253

Answer (score 1):

At one level, this is quite easy to do. However, at another, there can be some
complications, depending on what you really want to do.

Emacs supports a command line switch -l to tell emacs where to find the config
file. So, from a very simple perspective, you could just create two wrapper
scripts my-spacemacs.sh and my-plainemacs.sh and inside them have the scripts
call emacs with a specific -l /path/to/config. You can pass $* to pick up other
command line arguments if you want.

The potential problem with this approach is that emacs will still use .emacs.d
to store all sorts of other information, including possibly elpa packages and
this could cause problems. To be safer, it is better to keep things completely
separate.

If you don't need to run both versions at the same time, the easy solution is to
have to separate directories, such as ~/.spacemacs-emacs.d and ~/plain-emacs.d
and then have a sym link called .emacs.d which points to whichever of the
versions you want to run. The two main problems with this approach is that you
need to reset the symbolic link whenever you want to change emacs flavors and
this won't work if you want to run both versions at the same time.

I guess we really need to know about your actual use case - why do you need two
different configurations? Knowing this could help identify a better approach.

As an example, I use org mode and babel to manage my emacs config. I have a
number of different versions and a simple script which I can run to generate
whichever init.el file I want from the different org files. I have a minimal.org
file, which has the most minimal emacs configuration I can bare and I have my
standard init.org which generates my working init.el and then I have an
experimental.org which is used to generate an init.el file which I use for
experimenting with new configurations or packages. It is trivial to switch
configurations, but I never need to run two different configurations at the same
time.

I often like to check out some of the other pre-cooked emacs setups, like
spacemacs, prelude, etc. for these, I just grab the current git version and use
a symbolic link to point .emacs.d at the root fo the git repo I want to
experiment with.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the following approach:

create a directory ~/spacemacs.
extract/copy the spacemacs .emacs.d into ~/spacemacs (so that it is ~/spacemacs/.emacs.d).
create a desktop link called Spacemacs (or menu entry) and enter the following command:

```
    HOME=$HOME/spacemacs emacs
```

You can also start spacemacs from the shell with this command.
This way, you can run vanilla emacs and spacemacs simultaneously, each with its own configuration directory and elpa repository.  The only disadvantage might be that you need to change a directory level upward to reach your real home directory, not the „fake” one set via the variable.
btw, this is how I run several emacs versions and configurations, as needed for diverse stuff.

Comment: Redefining $HOME will break a lot of programs, that rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution seems to be using chemacs: https://github.com/plexus/chemacs

Comment: superseded by https://github.com/plexus/chemacs2 it seems: 'Chemacs 2 supports early-init.el, Chemacs 1 does not.' In that repository it also mentions a more "emacs-native" alternative, 'Emacs 29 introduces [–init-directory](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/log/?qt=grep&q=init-directory)'

Comment: I can recommend chemacs for emacs users that want to use several configurations (inits) interchangeably over a longer period of time. It is useful to for instance set up a "plain" emacs, a doom-emacs, and a spacemacs .., or a "development profile" and a more stable one. It can also be used in a way that the separate configurations are related to the XDG-directory specification.